# Change text file syntax highlighter in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, glsl, syntax-highlighting

How can I change the Syntax Highlighter for a text file in VS?

I'm writing a few Shader programs in GLSL (OpenGL Shading Language) and I usually save these files as text files. How can I change the Syntax Highlighting so it conforms to a C file since C syntax is very similar to GLSL syntax.

Note: I have VS 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [NShader project](https://github.com/samizzo/nshader) seems to target Visual Studio rather than VS Code as per a previous answer. I have never used it but it might be worth looking into?

Answer (score 1):

[GLSL language integration extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanielScherzer.GLSL) is definitely worth a look if you are using Visual Studio 2017.

(Note that C/C++ programs compiled with Visual Studio 2015 / 2017 are binary compatible, which should simplify upgrading.)

Answer (score -1):

[This extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=slevesque.shader) of slevesque is very useful.
You have 3 different highlights: HSLS, GLSL and Cg.

Comment: That extension says it is for VS Code.